# Mysql Server Database showing only information_schema database

Tags: mysql, database, client-server, lan

Initially i tried connecting the Mysql server database from another machine connected in LAN from my machine.

I successfully connected and i worked with that. After shutdowning  the both machines.

Later again i tried to create new database i mean in the connected Mysql server database from my machine it worked. But in the Mysql server database machine showing only information_schema database alone. And also i unable to create new database in the connected Mysql server database machine.

I tried with GRANT & PRIVILEGES cmds but it showing access is denied .

For Your Information

Mysql in my PC and Mysql server database in another machine having the same user name and password.
This is the cause for the error.

What shall i do now ?

Comment: your mysql db is linux server or windows..First login in mysql on your db server with host localhost and root password..and check it is showing databases or not.

Comment: No i  checked in the mysql server DB machine with the command as mysql -hlocal host -uroot -pamdin

Comment: I went but i checked show databses. It showing only the information_schema Database only

Comment: check data directory in your configuration file my.cnf if linux and my.ini if windows..go to your data directory and check what folders are there exist.If you get there only information schema and not getting your db's then search if your db exists on your machine in any other directory..